# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the 1D Laplace (Poisson) Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a couple of questions regarding the eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectors of the 1D Laplace (in general Poisson) equation. Note: It is possible that some of my questions are wrong, as I am very weak in this topic.

Given $-u''(x) = 0, x \in \Omega$, where $\Omega := (0,1)$ and $u(0) = u(1) = 0$, we want to solve this by finite differencing. So using the $O(h^{2})$ central FDM on a grid of $n+1$ points, $x_0, x_1, ..., x_n$, where $u(x_0) = u_0$ and $u(x_n) = u_n$ are known to be $0$, we want to solve for $u(x_1) = u_1, ... , u(x_{n-1}) = u_{n-1}$. The coefficient matrix $A$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{(n-1) \times (n-1)}$, which corresponds to the linear system $A \vec{u} = \vec{0}$, is:

\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & \ldots & \ldots \\
\vdots & -1 & 2 & -1 & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}

I am asked to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix $A$. I looked for the solution in a book and found out that I am supposed to link this with a Sturm-Liouville problem but I don't know which one.

So below is the list of my questions:

1- ) How do I find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix $A$? In particular, with which Sturm-Liouville problem should I link my problem with?,

2-) In general, if the RHS vector or source function $f$ is not $0$, or the boundary conditions are different (Possibly non-zero Dirichlet conditions or Neumann conditions or Robin conditions), will the Sturm-Liouville problem change?,

3-) Why does solving the appropriate Sturm-Liouville problem linked with our problem give the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of our coefficient matrix $A$ (and also the eigenvalues of the discrete Laplacian)? Are there any references or books that I can read regarding the theory of this?

Thank you.

Comment: 1) _Discrete Cosine and Sine Transforms: General Properties, Fast Algorithms and Integrer Approximations,_ by Vladimir Britanak, Patrick C. Yip, and Kamisetty R. Rao